# PyCharm: import numpy as np not registering.

Tags: python, numpy, import, pycharm

I'm doing my best to figure out this problem i'm having with Numpy. It simply won't work, i've got PyCharm, Python 3.7, Numpy 1.14.5(Recommended version of Numpy for PyCharm/Python 3.7) it's frustrating me, as I think its whats holding me back from getting my actual face recognition program working.

Comment: Did you update your PyCharm and Numpy?

Comment: Explain what error you are getting is the import fsiling?

Comment: stack trace would be helpful